# Safari can't connect to the server "localhost"

Tags: macos

Okay, I am a beginner with all this, so don't expect me know much. Let me know if this is the wrong place to ask this. What tags should I have used? THANKS a lot for your time.

**Background**

I have a CGI script saved in /Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables.

I used to be able to run the script using the URL: `http://localhost/cgi-bin/filename`,

**Problem**

But now, Safari can't connect to the server?!  Once or twice it begins to load then stays for a long time and eventually the same error comes up.

What could the problem be?

**Extra Q's**

I found my apache2 folder in /private/log/apache2 should this be moved?

Can I somehow run this script on something else without a server? Terminal works, but it is too hard to read.

Comment: is localhost up, is a server running ? That should be the first step.

Comment: Okay, sorry, but how to I check that?

Comment: @Jon The same way you checked for the script, type it into Safari `http://localhost/`

Comment: Oh, ya, I've tried that before. NO same error.

Comment: Do this in a terminal: "ps -eaf | grep httpd"; if you get anything more than the "grep" line, things are running (but may need restarted). Otherwise Apache isn't running at all. (I've had occasions on other platforms where Apache will be running with httpd processes, but not respond to requests, so it is worth a check to see if there are processes running.)

Comment: `501 15383 15378   0   0:00.00 ttys003    0:00.00 grep httpd` appeared when I ran the grep line... so I guess it's not running?

Comment: Nope seems not.

Comment: If I double-click /usr/sbin/httpd I get the following:

`httpd: Could not open configuration file /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: No such file or directory
logout`

Does this mean I need to put apache2 into the etc folder? Why wasn't it there to begin with?

Comment: THANKS! That solved my problem! The folder wasn't there (Should I post this in the Answer section?)... more checks: `apachectl configtest` and @Kerri Shotts worked this time too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like you are using Mac's built-in server and maybe somewhere along the line, web sharing was disabled.

Go to your System Preferences and enable Web Sharing.

To be sure httpd has started do what [@Kerri mentioned in the comments](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16116/safari-cant-connect-to-the-server-localhost#comment-17628)

```
ps -eaf | grep httpd
```

which will display all processes that contain httpd as well as the Process ID

if you only get something like the following

```
501 22299 22030   0   0:00.00 ttys001    0:00.00 grep httpd
```

grep is the only process running referencing httpd

At this point try stopping and restarting the server manually

```
sudo httpd -k stop  
sudo httpd -k restart
```

Look also into the Console.app log and filter to see what information you can get from there.

If it is enabled you should get the following on pointing to localhost within a browser

> **It works!**

So far so good, the server is running.

Now to navigate to the cgi-bin folder, if you used the scripts before then it should be mapped already in your configuration.

You could get

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access
>   /cgi-bin/ on this server.

or an Internal Server Error if you went straight to the script

and you can `chmod 755` the script and that should give you the correct permission to run it.

You can also check the access and error logs to see what's up

/var/log/apache2/access_log
/var/log/apache2/error_log

/var is the symbolic link to private/var

Comment: Unfortunately, I've restarted the Web Sharing many times but it still doesn't work. I've run them before (after changing the permissions) but still nothing... Thanks though. Seems like the problem is deeper than I thought

Comment: @Jon what does it say in your logs? Check `/var/log/apache2/error_log` after you try and view the web page.

Comment: @ghoppe see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16116/safari-cant-connect-to-the-server-localhost#comment-17634

Comment: This might be helpful to somebody as well if you are seeing "apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed" -  https://linux.101hacks.com/unix/httpd-apr-sockaddr-info-get-error/

Answer (score 0):

Run the following to see any **other** non-obvious errors. I did all the above and have had this Mac (without rebuilding -just upgrading and upgrading etc.) pre2004 - just kept upgrading - so there was quite a history on this mac. There were some skeletons in the closet. I JUST upgraded to Mountain Lion when the lid came off my web server.

Run this - look for errors on the output line.

`sudo httpd -E /private/var/log/apache2`

I had a module installed (SVN – but that is merely a detail) and it was loaded in the *other* category at the end of the httpd.conf file.

Here is the output of the command line – it pointed to the issue:

> httpd: Syntax error on line 500 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /private/etc/apache2/other/svn.conf: Cannot load /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_dav_svn.so into server: dlopen(/usr/libexec/apache2/mod_dav_svn.so, 10): image not found

I renamed the svn.conf file to svn.deletedconffile and apache started right up. I also had to chmod to **755** all my Sites files – not 644 which is suggested on some sites.

Answer (score -2):

if you created a username.conf file in mountain lion delete it. After doing so restart apache and all should be well :)

Comment: How should this help in accessing `localhost`? The user.conf files are only needed to access `localhost/~user`